# Which of these properties is not true of the directional derivative?

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

In Arnold's *Ordinary Linear Equations*, 1st edition, chapter 2, section 10, subsection 3, the author pulls what is just about the dirtiest, cruelest, most evil trick which could be imagined from an expositor of mathematics. Here is the setup:

"We denote by $F$ the set of all infinitely differentiable functions $f : U \rightarrow \textbf{R}$. Let $\textbf{v}$ be an infinitely differentiable vector field in $U$. The derivative of a function of $F$ in the direction of the field $\textbf{v}$ again belongs to $F$. Thus differentiation in the direction of the field $\textbf{v}$ is a mapping $L_v : F \rightarrow F$ of the algebra of infinitely differentiable functions into itself. Let us consider several properties of this mapping:

1. $L_v(f + g) = L_vf + L_vg$
2. $L_v(fg) = fL_vg + gL_vf$
3. $L_{u+v} = L_v + L_u$
4. $L_{fu} = fL_u$
5. $L_uL_v = L_vL_u$

($f$ and $g$ are smooth functions and $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ are smooth vector fields)."

And then comes the punch to the gut, in tiny text:

<sub>"**Problem 1.** Prove properties 1-5, except for the one which is not true."</sub>

I believe the falsehood is number 4, $L_{fu} = fL_u$. The reason is because $f$ must be a function from a vector field to another vector field to be applied to $u$, but $L_u$ transforms a real-valued function to another real-valued function, so it doesn't make sense to apply the same $f$ to both $u$ and $L_u$.

Is that correct?

Comment: I strongly suspect that $fu$ and $fL$ in property 4 are pointwise multiplications, much like in the right-hand side of property 2, and that $f$ is a function $U\to\mathbf R$.

Comment: @Arthur Oooh. Then property 4 would be trivially true.

Comment: @copper.hat How do you figure? They have previously used $f$ to denote scalar functions, and scalar functions only. Why do you suspect that that changes when we get to point 4?

Comment: @copper.hat Again, I reiterate: You claim $f$ is not a scalar function, and / or that $fu$ is not pointwise scaling. What makes you say that? What else could it possibly be?

Comment: @copper.hat Oh, I see now. A classic case of you saying exactly what you mean, and me insisting that you're saying something else. I'm sorry. (That sounded more sarcastic than I meant to...)

Comment: @copper.hat: But $L_{fu} g = (fu) \cdot \nabla g = f (u \cdot \nabla g) = f L_u g$. What difference would it make if $f$ is a constant or a function?

Comment: @AlexD: Regarding the question, look up “commutator of vector fields“ and have a new look at property 5.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm sorry, your discussion has left me behind. I understand that $f$ is a scalar function in property 4, but how do you apply a scalar function to a vector field? When Arthur said that $fu$ denotes pointwise multiplication, I took it to mean that $f$ is applied to the magnitude of the vectors at each point in the field, and gives their new magnitude, i.e. $f$ is used to scale all the vectors in the field. If that was so, then the field *would* certainly point in the same direction, and property 4 would be trivially true.

Comment: I misinterpreted the statement "Let $\textbf{v}$ be an infinitely differentiable vector field in $U$." I took $U$ to be a set of smooth differentiable vector fields, not $\mathbb{R}^n$. Ignore my above remarks.

Comment: I deleted my misleading remarks.

Comment: Unless I have further misunderstood, Property 5 is the culprit. Suppose $U = \mathbb{R}$. Let $f(x) = {1 \over 2} x^2$, $u(x) =1$, $v(x) = x$. Then $(L_u f)(x)= x$, $(L_vf)(x)= x^2$. Then $(L_v (L_u f))(x)= x$ and $(L_u (L_v f))=2x$, so in general, $L_v L_u \neq L_u L_v$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, wish I could accept that answer!